# AppSelfHostBase not resolving

Tags: unit-testing, servicestack

I have service stack in a .netcore xUnit test. I cannot resolve AppSelfHostBase. I downloaded the latest repo of servicestack and its there in the Servicestack namespace. But I cannot resolve it in my project. AppSelfHost works fine. Anyone know why? I am on ServiceStack 5.4.1

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For .NET Core [AppSelfHostBase in in the ServiceStack.Kestre](http://docs.servicestack.net/netcore#appselfhostbase-source-compatible-self-host)l NuGet package.